# How do I mask https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET as a subdomain?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3

How do I mask https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET as a subdomain (static) using dns entries?

My Amazon bucket name is `static.gamer-source.com`

CNAME entry is: `static CNAME static.gamer-source.com.s3.amazonaws.com.` (this is setup through ENOM's host record manager)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buckets are accessible using `<bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com`. Amazon provides a few options on how to access these resources using alternate means. Details are provided in the [S3 docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/index.html?VirtualHosting.html).

Comment: When I do that, `<bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com` turns into `<bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com.` with an extra period which breaks it

Comment: @Webnet That period is actually the DNS system signifying an absolute domain name. Your CNAME resolves fine for me.

Comment: Looks like `static.gamer-source.com` is working just fine. I'm getting an Access Denied error from AWS.

Comment: Bah you're right, now that I've stepped away for a while it's resolving.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what ErikA said, it's worth noting that you can't use SSL with a custom hostname like yours.  Since your question included HTTPS in the URL, I assume that's something you're looking to do.

Since Amazon doesn't have your SSL certificate, they can't authenticate HTTPS traffic for your domain.

More info:  http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host.html

Comment: Is this still the case in 2015?

Comment: @ChrisHarrison Though late,but yes. You need to upload your certificate files to AWS via CLI (no other way) and configure it to work for a custom domain